# Can Application Insights merge Azure.Mobile.Server.Files activity with Azure Storage blob diagnostic logs?

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-blob-storage, azure-application-insights

When a client calls `GetStorageTokenAsync` on the server, it gets a token that can read, write, or delete objects on the target container.

The activity done on this container is more or less hidden from my application unless I scan the logs.

Therefore I'm left to guess, or do some cumbersome programming to determine what the files where, the content of the files, determine what changed, etc...

I want to gather empirical evidence of what a given userID did with a certain known token Shared Access Signature, and aggregate the into either an administrative console like Application Insights, or some other tool that will allow programmatic response to the user's actions.

**Question**

What is the best way to align the actions a user takes, with a given Shared Access Signature (specifically in the context of the Nuget package `Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Files`?

Answer (score 0):

> and aggregate the into either an administrative console like Application Insights, or some other tool that will allow programmatic response to the user's actions.

There is not a tool or service which support it until now. I am afraid that you need to develop this tool by yourself. Storage Analytics Log stored in the $logs container of your storage account.  All the logs are written to a text file line by line.

> What is the best way to align the actions a user takes, with a given Shared Access Signature

Based on the [Storage Analytics Log Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/Storage-Analytics-Log-Format), we can only get whether a storage operation is authenticated by Shared Access Signature or account key by **'authentication-type'** (If the operation is authenticated by Shared Access Signature, the value of authentication-type will be ‘sas’). We can’t get the operations which related to a given Shared Access Signature.

Azure Storage Analytics log also contains the requester-ip-address which could identity the client which send the storage operate request. If the IP address of client is static, it will help you get all the actions which the specific user taked.